# Getting source directory's path while in WPF's design mode

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to retrieve some contents from a file that lies in source directory when user is in designmode (viewing .xaml file in designer)

My current code looks like:

```
#if DEBUG
            if ((bool)(System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(System.Windows.DependencyObject)).DefaultValue)) // design mode
            {
                var f = new System.IO.StreamReader(@".\somedir\myfile.txt");
                // do something with data from that file
                f.Close();
            }
#endif
```

but the current directory in this case is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE` and my file is not there at all.

I've tried changing current dir by:

`System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`

but this leads to something like:

`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Designer\ShadowCache\ckauoyuj.mbg\vihlqa20.ba2`

which contains only `.exe` and `.pdb` files - no files marked as `Content` in there

**I don't want to attach this file as a resource**

Comment: For future readers, this is a better solution moving forward. My original answer was in .Net Framework 4.0 which Microsoft stopped supporting in 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much easier way, just declare a method like this:

```
    public static void GetCurrentSourcePath([CallerFilePath] string path = "")
    {

    }
```

Path will have what you are looking for.

Comment: how do you use this ?

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer**
For future readers

The answer below, although it will still work, was written for .Net 4.0 which is no longer supported by Microsoft (End of life was 2016)

[Marco's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2157455/marco) answer above using the [CallerFilePathAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute?view=net-5.0)  is the solution I would use moving forward.

**Original Answer**

If you are after the folder where the source code exists, during design and run time, use

```
var trace = new StackTrace(true);
var frame = trace.GetFrame(0);
var sourceCodeFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(frame.GetFileName());
```

If you are after the bin/debug or bin/release folder at design time ...

Since the code base root folder can change from machine to machine, but the output folder for the project is the same across machines (and usually relative to the code base root), you can use the code above with

```
Path.Combine(sourceCodeFile, outputFolder);
```

where outputFolder is a string constant that has the value of the output folder on the Build tab of the project Properties window.

NOTE: Changes to code run during design time are not always picked up immediately. Sometimes you will have to

- Recompile to project.
- Close all design/code windows that are affected by the change.
- Run the application
- All the above

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, this is a working solution. I'm still looking for a more elegant solution because this one needs to provide relative path to the sources' root folder and moving the file entails the need of changing the code. But if I find none I will accept your answer :)

Comment: The sources root folder is obtained from the StackTraceFrame. If you move the project, the value returned from this will change accordingly. Unfortunately, I am yet to figure out how to obtain the relative path from the source to the output folder. If I figure it out, I will update the answer.

Comment: This is working as excepted in design time VS10 for me. Instead of DTE and many Path wanna-be solutions. Nice.